# Switching logic in Apex method based on Boolean parameter

Tags: apex

There is an Apex method where are are checking whether the status of the campaign is Extinct or not:

```
public static Boolean isExtinct(Campaign vCampaign) {
        return (vCampaign.Status__c == 'Extinct');
    }
```

There is another Apex method with similar logic, the only difference is that we have added one more condition to check whether Is_Logged_in_User__c is true or not.

```
public static Boolean isExtinctForLiggedInUser(Campaign vCampaign) {
        return (vCampaign.Status__c == 'Extinct'
                && vCampaign.Is_Logged_in_User__c);
    }
```

As you see, I have defined 2 methods. Is it possible to define only one method, and based on some Boolean parameter, I can switch the logic?

I can use if-else condition, but I am looking for a cleaner approach.

Comment: Take a look at [Strategy design pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns#Strategy). [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of Boolean logic:

```
public static Boolean isCampaignExtinct(Campaign vCampaign, Boolean forCurrentUser) {
    return vCampaign.Status__c == 'Extinct' && (!forCurrentUser || vCampaign.Is_Logged_in_User__c);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If both methods are used, then keep them both as their names are quite descriptive. Below is one way to re-use a bit of the logic. There are lots of options.

```
public static Boolean isExtinct(Campaign vCampaign) {
    return vCampaign.Status__c == 'Extinct';
}

public static Boolean isExtinctForLoggedInUser(Campaign vCampaign) {
    return isExtinct(vCampaign) && vCampaign.Is_Logged_in_User__c;
}
```